# Generating set of a quotient of $\Bbb R[x,y]$ over $\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the commutative ring with identity $R=\Bbb R[x,y]$ of polynomials in two variables $x,y$ with coefficients in the real numbers. Let $I_p$ denote the ideal generated in $R$ by $p(x,y)=x+3y^2$. It's a fact that $Q=R/I_p$ is an algebra over the real numbers. The question is to find a set of generators of this algebra (over the real numbers).

P.S. I know it must be an infinite set, but need help to describe it.

Comment: Why do you think it is an infinite set? Do you mean a generating set as an algebra or as a module?

Comment: As a module, Tobias.

Comment: Hint: If a module $M$ is generated by some set $S$ then any quotient of $M$ is generated by the image of $S$ in the quotient. In your case, the original module is generated by products of powers of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

As a unitary algebra over $\Bbb R$, it is generated by $[y]$ because in $Q$ we have $[y]^2=-[x]/3$, so $[y]$ also generates $[x]$, using the algebra operations. 
(Here, for an $f\in R\ $ I used $[f]$ for the equivalence class $f+I_p$ in $R$, w.r.t. the equivalence relation $f\sim g \iff f-g\,\in I_p$.)